# Export Dropdown Selection in Kendo Editor to Word Document

Tags: kendo-ui, export, kendo-asp.net-mvc, docx, kendo-editor

I've been trying to get a selected dropdown option to appear in a Word Document on export.
The current default behavior is that all option tags appear in the exported document with no indication of which was selected. (This makes sense that this behavior would occur since the export function is simply exporting all the html as plain text).

So far, these are the approaches I've tried (none of which work):
-Capture the export event before it is sent to the controller via the javascript execute event (thus being able to strip out any unwanted text). The issue is the execute event and exportas event are asynchronous, so I can't modify the file before the export event call is executed.

-Modify the text on the controller side before it is converted to a Word document and downloaded (the text is sent through without special characters, which makes it nearly impossible to parse)

-Attempt to replace the dropdown with a kendo autocomplete widget (this would also be an acceptable solution). The widget does not render properly inside the document. All of the datasource options are there and even filters corretly, but it does not style correctly or open.

Has anyone else been able to find a solution to this problem or have another approach I could use?

EDIT:
As per requested, here is a screenshot of the base code:
[image: c sharp code]
[image: razor]

Comment: my code looks literally exactly like the example here: http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/editor/import-export#overview. with a select tag with options inside the value field.

Comment: I've added screenshots at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

My initial idea on how you could accomplish this:
1. Pull that select list out of your editor. 
2. Bind an event handler to the change event of your list to add the value of your list into the editor. Are you using JQuery in your project? It's a dependency for Kendo so this ought to work:

```
$("#selectListId").on("change", function () { 
     $("#editor").val( $("#selectListId").val());
});
```

In reality though I'm guessing this approach will be used to populate some template of text with values selected by the user? In that case,  you may want to save the template first before applying the value selected.

Now that you've identified you need that dropdown menu to be usable on the exported word document, attempt the following:

1. Create a new word document.
2. In that word document, open the Developer tab. (If you don't know about it, google how to enable it)
3. Insert a new Dropdown Menu Content Control using the Developer tab.
4. Select this content control, then open Properties menu item on Developer tab.
5. Update the content control with your values:
   [image: ExampleOfContentControl]
6. Save this word document.
7. Use the Kendo Editor Import to import this document containing your template.
8. Attempt exporting what was just imported.

If that works and the editor has editable dropdowns from that content control, I will be very surprised... Good luck!

Comment: I thought about doing it this way, but the requirements for the project require the dropdowns to be inline in the editor.
They will be prepopulated by server code. The user will fill out the editor, using the dropdowns to help prompt them, but ultimately, everything is required to be editable once it's downloaded in docx form.

Comment: You may be better served by just creating a nice .docx file template with the content control dropdown menus in it for the user to edit, and then import that document into the kendo editor and try exporting that? You may be able to save the code that is imported as the default value to accomplish this then...